# VIM Window panes changing orientation

Tags: vim

How can I go from a formation like this

```
..........................................................
.                            .                           .
.                            .                           .
.             3              .                           .
.                            .                           .
.                            .                           .
..............................              1            .
.                            .                           .
.                            .                           .
.             2              .                           .
.                            .                           .
.                            .                           .
.                            .                           .
..........................................................
```

to one like this

```
..........................................................
.                                                        .
.                                                        .
.                             3                          .
.                                                        .
.                                                        .
..........................................................
.                             .                          .
.                             .                          .
.                             .                          .
.            2                .             1            .
.                             .                          .
.                             .                          .
.                             .                          .
..........................................................
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Control-W K</kbd> (note that the "K" must be shift+k (uppercase k)) will move the window your cursor is in to the very top of the screen, making it full width.

See "`:help window-moving`".

Answer (score 4):

You can use `^w H`, `^w J`, `^w K`, and `^w L` to move the split windows. (Note the capital letters. If you were to do without holding shift, it would just change which window was focused).

So with your example, you could just move to window 3 and press `^W K`.

Comment: These are definitely not native Vim commands.  See my answer.

Comment: Shoot, forgot that they were `^W (letter)` and not just `^(letter)`.